# How do I achieve dynamic linking with sqlite and firedac?

Tags: sqlite, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

For dynamic linking, the documentation [Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)) says that one should edit the `firedac.inc` file located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\data\firedac`.

I can only find `firedac.inc` in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples`.

If I copy it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\data\firedac`, and enable dynamic linking (i.e. remove dot as indicated `$UNDEF FireDAC_SQLITE_STATIC`) that does not seem to result in dynamic linking (I have a custom sqlite3.dll in same folder as exe).

How do I achieve dynamic linking with sqlite and firedac?

I am using Tokyo, although the same incorrect documentation exists for Rio.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Embarcadero Support and they confirmed this is a problem with the Professional edition, where certain source code files are missing.

The representative filed this issue with reference RS-95075. If you need the source code files you could contact Embarcadero Support.